# Are there OAuth 2 server side PHP or Java implementations?

Tags: java, php, oauth, oauth-2.0

If there is more then one implementation, which one is better/mostly maintained?

Specifically for OAuth 2.0 Draft 12.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taken from [OAuth Wiki](http://wiki.oauth.net/w/page/25236487/OAuth-2), there seems to be one PHP implementation called [oauth2-php](http://code.google.com/p/oauth2-php/) which supports [IETF draft v9](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-09). Since OAuth2 is still a draft, it will probably be hard to find more implementations.

Comment: Well, about this one I know. it's called oauth2-php, btw. I was wandering if there are any other implementations that are newer.

Comment: Correct, it's oauth2-php, thanks. I don't know of any newer ones. At the end of the day, you can still write your own library and share it with the community.

Answer (score 10):

There is a more up-to-date version of the PHP OAuth2 library available at https://github.com/quizlet/oauth2-php It implements draft 20 of the spec, and will likely work with few or no changes once the final spec is released.

Answer (score 1):

See also the one from Ericsson labs: 
https://labs.ericsson.com/apis/oauth2-framework/

> The OAuth2 Framework allows you to protect your web resources using
>   the next generation OAuth, (http://oauth.net/2/) as well as accessing
>   OAuth2 protected resources, most notably the Facebook Graph API. The
>   API consists of libraries for building your own OAuth2 server as well
>   as client side access. The standard is still in draft mode so expect
>   some level of changes. Currently version 10 of the OAuth 2
>   specification is the one being supported.