# Java OAuth Server

Tags: java, open-source, oauth-2.0, oauth-provider

Are there any open source projects that enabled implementing OAuth Server? Apache Foundation ones?

Comment: Why are these OAuth server questions all of a sudden becoming so popular?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4875420/is-there-an-oauth-2-draft-12-server-side-php-and-java-implementations

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest using [the Spring Security Module](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/oauth/).  It's open source and the entire framework is very powerful.

Comment: I plan to use Guice for DI, I am not sure how Spring Security would bundle in with Guice??

Comment: According to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484568/is-it-possible-to-use-spring-security-with-google-guice there is no Spring/Guice integration. Here is a simple tutorial how to write custom AOP security check: http://jpz-log.info/archives/2009/11/04/guice-it-up-or-aop-can-be-made-simple-sometimes/

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at http://oauth.net/code/

in the Java section ;)