# Is it possible to use Spring Security with Google Guice?

Tags: java, spring-security, guice

I would like to change Spring Framework to Google Guice, because it's lighter and has almost everything I need. Is it possible to use Spring Security with Google Guice instead of Spring Framework?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  Spring Security makes extensive use of the core Spring Framework.

(I guess, *in theory* you could use Spring + Spring Security for the security filters, and Google Guice for the servlet wiring ... but I expect there would be a few traps and pitfalls on *that* road.)

Comment: Okey thanx for answer, I'm going to try Apache Shiro.